# How to sum items from largest value to smallest (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that will sum the items from a list, from largest to smallest, up to a certain value. (It´s an exercise on the "knapsack problem"). I have come up with this to find the largest valued item on the list and then add it to the variables `pt` and `vt`:

```
knapsack = []
l1 = [300.0, 400.0, 600.0, 1300.0, 2000.0]
l2 = [100.0, 400.0, 300.0, 700.0, 2000.0]
l3 = [0.3333333333333333, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5384615384615384, 1.0]
    
    while pt <= c:
        for i in range(len(l3):
            if i not in knapsack:
                if l3[i] > m:
                    m = l3[i]
                    v = l2[i]
                    p = l1[i]
                    knapsack.append(i)
                    
                if l3[i] == m and l1[i] < p:
                    m = l3[i]
                    v = l2[i]
                    p = l1[i]
                    knapsack.append(i)

            i += 1
        i = 0
        pt += p
        vt += v
```

However, I have not been able to make the `for` loop skip the previous largest value found, so it adds 400 to both `pt` and `vt` in every iteration. I tried solving that adding the i value to the `knapsack` list but it did not work.

OBS: the goal is to add to the knapsack the value with the largest value `l1` to weight `l2` ratio, for which I created a third list `l3`. If the ratio is the same, the tie-breaking criteria is the item with the smallest weight, that is why the `.sort()` function wouldn´t work – each value has 2 correspontant values in the other lists.

Comment: `for i in range(l3):` when `l3` is a list? This won't even run if you fixed the indentation and defined `pt` and `c` before you use them.

Comment: first of all:  `l3 = [l2[i]/l1[i] for i in range(len(l1)) ]`.

Comment: secondly:   `sorted(l3, reverse=True)` gives the reverse sorted list.

Comment: `for i in range(l3)` that mistake I made when I wrote the question, it di not make into the program itself. Sorry for that. `pt` and `c` were defined, I left it out to keep it short. Thanks!

Comment: If there are errors pointed out in your post, you should edit your post to amend the errors. @matusquela

Comment: Done. Thanks for the comprehension, first time posting a question here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
# the input lists
l1 = [300.0, 400.0, 600.0, 1300.0, 2000.0]
l2 = [100.0, 400.0, 300.0, 700.0, 2000.0]

# the result list
l3 = [l2[i]/l1[i] for i in range(len(l1)) ]


# the sorted list (highest to lowest)
reversed_sorted = sorted(l3, reverse=True)


# some value to be used as a limit
some_value = 3


the_total=0 # value to keep adding
for i in reversed_sorted:
    if the_total + i >  some_value:
        # if go above value then exit
        break
    else:
        the_total = the_total + i
        # otherwise add next item

# print result
print(the_total)
```

note that the final loop cna be condensed into a `list comprehension`.

Comment: Thank you, but I dont think that works because 1. The smaller values in `l2` are to be used as a tie-breaker criteria if there are equal values in `l3` (which there will be), so 400/400 has priority over 2000/2000 and 2. The values that are to be added are from lists `l1` and `l2`. So it's no use sorting `l3` and not changing the other 2 lists correspondently because then the values are all scrambled. Basically, every item has 3 correspondant values, in 3 different lists, which need to be avaluated by the program and I don't quite know how to do that

Comment: okay,  that should be specified in the original question in that respect as the answer provided solved the question given. It is recommended that you formulate a new question with your working to that point and what you are tried and probably a link to this question.